# Does GCC 7.3 omit the [[nodiscard]] attribute for reference returning member functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++17, nodiscard

I've got the following code utilizing the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute of **C++17**.

```
class SomeClass {
public: /** Methods **/
    [[nodiscard]] int getValue()  { return n; }
    [[nodiscard]] int &getRef()   { return n; }
    [[nodiscard]] int *getPtr()   { return &n; }

private: /** Members **/
    int n{5};
};

int main() 
{
    SomeClass object;

    object.getValue();
    object.getRef();
    object.getPtr();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with **GCC 7.3**, I've two warnings stating that the return value of two functions is ignored. The two functions detected by the compiler are the ones that don't return a reference, `getValue()` and `getPtr()`.

On the other hand, when compiled with **GCC 8.1** and above versions, the `getRef()` also causes a warning.

The [C++ support table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17) provided by GCC shows that the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute is fully supported as of version 7. It also has a white [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0189r1.pdf).

> Appearance of a `[[nodiscard]]` call as a potentially ­evaluated discarded­ value expression is discouraged unless explicitly cast to void.

So, is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Same for [gcc v7.5](https://godbolt.org/z/nvTYqneqh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug. It was fixed in GCC 8 as you have already realized.

Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80896